# Determining outliers based on two other columns

Tags: r

I have data in the form:

```
Length      Width     Weight    
1           2         4.5
1           2         4.5
1           2         6.1
1           2         4.5
1           3         9.1
1           3         9.05
1           3         9.2
1           3         9.07
1           3         10.2
```

For many lengths, and each one many widths.  However there are many weight errors like above.  What would be the best way to identify these errors.

Ultimately I would like something like

```
Length      Width     Weight     Quality   
1           2         4.5        good
1           2         4.5        good
1           2         6.1        bad
1           2         4.5        good
1           3         9.1        good
1           3         9.05       good
1           3         9.2        good
1           3         9.07       good
1           3         10.2       bad
```

My thinking so far, (without knowing the exact coding in R for them)  Would be to do something like.

```
for lengths in data$length
    for width in data$width
         avg=mean(data$weight[data$length == length & data$width == width]
         if (data$weight-avg)/avg  >0.1
              data$quality = "bad"
         else data$quality = "good"
```

I'm not sure how doable/practical this is to program in R, just wanted to explain my thinking and goal.

Some issues with that however is what to value to use as the "correct" value.  there I used mean, however in general the mode would probably work well.  Most of the "groups" are like the width 2, where all are the same value with an outlier (if there is one).  However there are some cases of groups like width 3 where even though nothing occurs more than once, it is pretty clear what the outlier is.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question well, but I guess you wanna calculate the average weight by group, and set the quality by certain condition.

**1.Get the data.**

```
data = data.frame(Length=c(rep(1,9)),Width=c(rep(2,4),rep(3,5)),Weight=c(4.5,4.5,6.1,4.5,9.1,9.05,9.2,9.07,10.2))
```

> data

Length Width Weight
1      1     2   4.50
2      1     2   4.50
3      1     2   6.10
4      1     2   4.50
5      1     3   9.10
6      1     3   9.05
7      1     3   9.20
8      1     3   9.07
9      1     3  10.20

**2.Mean group by the Lenght and Width**

```
library(dplyr)
by_Length_Width = group_by(data,Width,Length)
group = summarise(by_Length_Width,avg = mean(Weight))
data1 = left_join(data,group)
```

**3.Set the Quality column**

```
data1$quality = ifelse((data1$Weight-data1$avg)/data1$avg>0.1,"bad","good")
```

> data1
>     Length Width Weight   avg quality
>   1      1     2   4.50 4.900    good
>   2      1     2   4.50 4.900    good
>   3      1     2   6.10 4.900     bad
>   4      1     2   4.50 4.900    good
>   5      1     3   9.10 9.324    good
>   6      1     3   9.05 9.324    good
>   7      1     3   9.20 9.324    good
>   8      1     3   9.07 9.324    good
>   9      1     3  10.20 9.324    good
>   
>    By the way, for loop in for loop is not a efficient way in R :).

Comment: This gave me a really good way to calculate if there was a problem with a group, but the average doesn't work overall for my data set.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to achieve what you want is as follows:

Calculate the average weight for each Length and Width. Then define sensible thresholds that helps you identify the errors. Then just compare all values against those thresholds. You can do it relatively easy using dplyr functions.

Another way would be to generate a multivariate regression model using the Length and the Weight as regressors and weight as the dependent variable. Then you can define a confidence interval for your prediction and flag as "bad" all the guys that fall out of this confidence interval. For that you coud use the "lm" and "predict" function

Comment: I tried this, however the range of weights is so wide, .001 - 14 that the error on the smaller parts is too big and almost all of them get flagged.